# msaccess.exe opens while trying to release the object

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am opening a MS Access DB which is Password protected in vb.net using the folloing code:

```
Try
   oDB = oDBEngine.OpenDatabase(Name:=strFullFileName, Options:=False, _
                               ReadOnly:=False, Connect:="")

Catch ex As Exception

   strError = "File is password protected."
   Exit Function

End Try
```

But while releasing the object the msaccess.exe opens up automatically.

```
 **System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object)**
```

Could anyone help me, how to resolve the issue....

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using OpenDatabase to get the error, how about a connection string?

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
       "Data Source=" & strFile & ";" & _
       "Persist Security Info=False"
```

This will also give an error if a password is not supplied.